# Diagnose a memory leak in C++ code forming part of an R package, on Windows

Tags: c++, r, memory-leaks

I am writing an R package that includes C++ code, written by an external developer who is unable to help out.
The C++ code currently appears to have a memory leak: R's memory usage keeps increasing when the C++ code is run, and is not released until R is quit.  It is my task to neutralize this leak.

Because I am using Windows, and calling the C++ code through R, it is not clear how best to track down this leak.  My cunning plan was to use [valgrind](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-valgrind) in a Linux environment on Travis CI, but this [finds no problems](https://travis-ci.org/ms609/Quartet/jobs/615096238).

What is the best way to track down memory leaks?

Comment: [`clang -fsanitize=address`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) might catch a leak on Windows. Although if you say it is released at quitting time, you may need to take several heap snapshots during the program's runtime, check the allocation site, and figure out why these objects are not being freed.

Comment: Is this "another developer" someone in-house you could work with on solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately the other developer is a busy academic without the capacity to help out.

Comment: I would simplify. Write tests against just the C++ code, as simple as you can, and use any of the memory leak tracking tools available. A google for "c++ memory leak detection" will help.

Comment: The R on Travis is probably not set-up correctly for valgrind. I have had success with https://github.com/wch/r-debug/blob/master/debugging-r.md for debugging memory issues in an R package.

Answer (score 1):

I have had partial success by adding a separate call to R with valgrind to my .travis.yml.

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages: valgrind
    after_success:
      - R -d "valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes" --vanilla < tests/testthat/valgrind.R
```

Ideally I'd've run tests/testthat.R, but because `R -d` runs interactively, I've had to create a separate file tests/testthat/valgrind.R for tests:

```
library(testthat)

# Load the package
library(pkgload)
load_all()

# This may run during build in root working directory,
# then again with R -d from tests wd.
if (dir.exists('testthat')) setwd('testthat/tests')

testFiles <- list.files(pattern = 'test\\-.*\\.R', full.names= TRUE)

# Test files using expect_doppleganger will fail in interactive mode.
# Remove them.
lapply(testFiles[-c(3, 6)], source)
```

This doesn't feel like an optimal solution... but it is sufficient for my immediate needs.

Comment: You could also try `R -d ... CMD check <tar.gz>`.